# Javascript TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

Getting this error with some Javascript script: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'results[j].distance.text')

Tried adding "var results = []" as recommended in other posts, but didn't help.

```
function CalculatedRecommededDistance() {

event.preventDefault();

var origin = document.getElementById('pick_up_address').value;
var destination = document.getElementById('drop_off_address').value;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

var results = [];


service.getDistanceMatrix({
origins: [origin],
destinations: [destination],
travelMode: 'DRIVING',
unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
avoidHighways: false,
avoidTolls: false,
avoidFerries: false

}, function(response, status) {
var originList = response.originAddresses;
var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputRecommended');
outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

//Display distance recommended value
for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
  var results = response.rows[i].elements;
  for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
    outputDiv.innerHTML += results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
      results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
  }
}
});
}
```

Comment: probably means: `results[j].distance` is undefined. console.log(results) in the loop, to see if you are getting what you expect. or the response before the loop. note: `var results = [];` has no effect on the code.

Comment: try `console.log(results)` under the `var results = response.rows[i].elements;` and see what you have inside the variable `results`

Comment: You are using two result variables. One in the function, other in for loop. Try using another variable if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`Javascript TypeError: undefined is not an object` that means you're trying to treat `undefined` value as an `Object`. (simply: trying to get data from `undefined` value)

you can safely ignore this error by using `?`. As `results[j]?.distance?.text`. But this not grantee you will get the expected result. So, first `console.log(result)` and see that expected objects are in that output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding the "?"s removes the error. Have the feeling from your comments that's just papering over the underlying issue, though.

I get the following from console.log (result) -- both when placed before and after the problematic line of code: 

[Log] [{distance: {text: "639 km", value: 638918}, duration: {text: "7 hours 41 mins", value: 27676}, status: "OK"}] (1)

Answer (score 0):

check if you result has distance and duration Property befor you get it:

```
function CalculatedRecommededDistance() {

event.preventDefault();

var origin = document.getElementById('pick_up_address').value;
var destination = document.getElementById('drop_off_address').value;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

var results = [];


service.getDistanceMatrix({
origins: [origin],
destinations: [destination],
travelMode: 'DRIVING',
unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
avoidHighways: false,
avoidTolls: false,
avoidFerries: false

}, function(response, status) {
var originList = response.originAddresses;
var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputRecommended');
outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

//Display distance recommended value
for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
  var results = response.rows[i].elements;
  for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
   if (result[j].hasownproperty("distance") && result[j].hasownproperty("duartion")){
    outputDiv.innerHTML += results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
      results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
  }
}
}
});
}
```